# Avoid merged cells in pandas to_excel method

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a multiindex dataframe which I have to save as an excel file. When I use pandas method "to_excel" to do so, I get a nice table which incorporates merged cells. Here is an example of how such a table looks like:

[image: example]

Unfortunately, filtering the first column of this table is very problematic in excel since excel does not understand that the merged cells belong together: 
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1955-excel-filter-merged-cells.html

That's why I need the 'to_excel' method to save the dataframe like that:

[image: example2]

Is that possible?

By the way, that's the code which I used to produce the first table:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"animal": ("horse", "horse", "dog", "dog"), "color of fur": ("black", "white", "grey", "black"), "name": ("Blacky", "Wendy", "Rufus", "Catchy")})

mydf = df.set_index(["animal", "color of fur"])

mydf.to_excel("some_path_here")
```

Comment: Do you need Multiindex? If simply create columns from index - `mydf = mydf.reset_index()` then all working nice...

Comment: In principle you are right but the muliindex has the advantage that the columns are bold. But shure, I can live with that. Thank you!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [`merge_cells=False`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) parameter:

```
mydf.to_excel("some_path_here", merge_cells=False)
```

From [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

> **merge_cells** : boolean, default True
>
> Write MultiIndex and Hierarchical Rows as merged cells.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility would be to insert the dataframe to excel with xlwings (requries excel installation), with the drawback that index and columns are not formatted, so MaxU's answer is superior.

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"animal": ("horse", "horse", "dog", "dog"), "color of fur": ("black", "white", "grey", "black"), "name": ("Blacky", "Wendy", "Rufus", "Catchy")}).set_index(["animal", "color of fur"])

with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
    wb = xw.Book()
    wb.sheets[0].range("A1").value = df
    wb.save(r"test.xlsx")
    wb.close()
```