# Pandas, restore multiindex from excel with merge_cells=False

Tags: python, pandas

When I save a multiindex and multicolumn dataframe to excel. I have two options. With and without `merge_cells=False`. This SO Question explains that quite nicely:

[Avoid merged cells in pandas to_excel method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46600472/avoid-merged-cells-in-pandas-to-excel-method)

If I do use `merge_cells=False`, I would have to use `ffil` to fill up the merged cells with the previous cell which might be a bit dangerous because if there are truly Nans (not emerging from merged cell), they might be (falsely) overridden.

I could generat a tidy format by using `df.to_excel(writer, merge_cells=False)`

A multiindex dataframe like this one (https://pastebin.com/Me0QhwUy):

```
      AA1 AA2 CB1 BB2 CC1      
        a   a   b   b   c     d
    ng/mL N/A N/A  mL N/A EU/mL
0 1                            
A 1     1   1   1   1   1     1
  2     1   1   1   1   1     1
B 1     1   1   1   1   1     1
  2     1   1   1   1   1     1
C 1     1   1   1   1   1     1
  2     1   1   1   1   1     1
```

Would become (after reading the saved excel):

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, merge_cells=False)
writer.save()
writer.close()

df2 = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')

   0  1  AA1.a.ng/mL  AA2.a.N/A  CB1.b.N/A  BB2.b.mL  CC1.c.N/A  CC1.d.EU/mL
0  A  1            1          1          1         1          1            1
1  A  2            1          1          1         1          1            1
2  B  1            1          1          1         1          1            1
3  B  2            1          1          1         1          1            1
4  C  1            1          1          1         1          1            1
5  C  2            1          1          1         1          1            1
```

I am aware of the function [wide to long](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) but this function does assume common stubnames which are not present here.

How can I  restore the original multiindex dataframe from the saved excel (with `merged_cell=False`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameter `index_col` for `MultiIndex` in `read_excel` and then [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for `MultiIndex`:

```
d = {('AA1', 'a', 'ng/mL'): {('A', 1): 1,
  ('A', 2): 1,
  ('B', 1): 1,
  ('B', 2): 1,
  ('C', 1): 1,
  ('C', 2): 1},
 ('AA2', 'a', 'N/A'): {('A', 1): 1,
  ('A', 2): 1,
  ('B', 1): 1,
  ('B', 2): 1,
  ('C', 1): 1,
  ('C', 2): 1},
 ('BB2', 'b', 'mL'): {('A', 1): 1,
  ('A', 2): 1,
  ('B', 1): 1,
  ('B', 2): 1,
  ('C', 1): 1,
  ('C', 2): 1},
 ('CB1', 'b', 'N/A'): {('A', 1): 1,
  ('A', 2): 1,
  ('B', 1): 1,
  ('B', 2): 1,
  ('C', 1): 1,
  ('C', 2): 1},
 ('CC1', 'c', 'N/A'): {('A', 1): 1,
  ('A', 2): 1,
  ('B', 1): 1,
  ('B', 2): 1,
  ('C', 1): 1,
  ('C', 2): 1},
 ('CC1', 'd', 'EU/mL'): {('A', 1): 1,
  ('A', 2): 1,
  ('B', 1): 1,
  ('B', 2): 1,
  ('C', 1): 1,
  ('C', 2): 1}}
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print (df)

      AA1 AA2 BB2 CB1 CC1      
        a   a   b   b   c     d
    ng/mL N/A  mL N/A N/A EU/mL
A 1     1   1   1   1   1     1
  2     1   1   1   1   1     1
B 1     1   1   1   1   1     1
  2     1   1   1   1   1     1
C 1     1   1   1   1   1     1
```

---

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, merge_cells=False)
writer.save()
writer.close()

df2 = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', index_col=[0,1])
df2.columns = df2.columns.str.split('.', expand=True)
print (df2)
      AA1 AA2 BB2 CB1 CC1      
        a   a   b   b   c     d
    ng/mL N/A  mL N/A N/A EU/mL
A 1     1   1   1   1   1     1
  2     1   1   1   1   1     1
B 1     1   1   1   1   1     1
  2     1   1   1   1   1     1
C 1     1   1   1   1   1     1
  2     1   1   1   1   1     1
```

Comment: Mabye my question is obsolete. I was worried due to this old question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937650/pandas-reading-excel-with-merged-cells But I just tried and pandas reads merged cell flawlessly.